# Releasing a returned-by-reference NSString causes crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsstring, return-by-reference

The following method takes a double pointer to `NSString` and populates this with a value, as follows:

```
@implementation Exp
- (int) func:(NSString**) dpStr
{
    //------
    *dpStr = [self func_2];
    //------
}
```

Now it is being called like this:

```
int main ()
{
   NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] init];
   int retCode = [Exp func:&str];
   // <----- Now here I'm able to access value returned by func ------->

   [str release];    //  <--- It is crashing here 
}
```

Can anyone explain why it is crashing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This allocates an empty string:

```
NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

This *replaces* the previous value of `str` with a new string which is apparently already autoreleased; *the old value of `str` is leaked*:

```
int retCode = [Exp func:&str];
```

This attempts to release the *new* value of `str`, which is already balanced, so it's an overrelease and a crash happens:

```
[str release];
```

Neither the leading `+alloc/-init` nor the trailing `-release` are needed in this case, as the object is provided by `-func:`. All you need is:

```
NSString *str = nil;
[Exp func:&str];
// use str normally
```

Better would be to modify `-func:` to return the string directly:

```
NSString *str = [Exp func];
// use str normally
```

Then there is no need to pass it by address.

Comment: If i replace NSString with NSMutableString and do following in the function
- (int) func:(NSMutableString**) dpStr
       {
          ------
          [*dpStr setString:[self func_2]];
          ------
       }

Then i am able to release memory using [str release].

This fun is defined in library and i am calling this fun from my application which is statically linked with this library

Which approach is recommend …

Comment: The recommended approach is what I described in my answer. In Objective-C, you do not need to provide buffers for strings and the like; the operating system usually handles it for you.

Comment: Please suggest which approach should i take for iOS application

Comment: I already *did*. iOS doesn't differ from any other Objective-C target here.